# Using multiple data streams to correlate event positions

Tags: c++, algorithm, dataset, comparison, time-series

I have a set of signals that I am trying to correlate with each other to determine the liklihood that an event took place.

Signal A has accurate event marks but may miss some or inadvertently capture unwanted ones.
Signal B has many noisy events many of which will be wrong but capture details missing from A.
Signal C has a precise occurrence of the events but the positions may be displaced and stretched in either direction.

Is there a methodology for finding the actual event points from this?

I was thinking of scaling the closest matching events of Signal C to the nearest events of Signal A, where the inbetween events of Single C would scale between those landmark points.  Signal C would then be compared to Signal B to find the nearest match to the scaled points of Signal C.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: I think you need a more concrete description of your problem. One example might be: Signal A is black and white time elapsed video of a room. Signal B is low resolution continuous video of the same room. Signal C is high resolution motion capture video from multiple rooms. The solution might be different depending on the problem domain.